# controller viewdata object into jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I am new to mvc and jquery 
In my controller I have 
ViewData["a"]="true";
I want to access the viewdata object in jquery
<% if(ViewData["a"] == "true")%>
{
$('#div1').show();
}
The above jquery doesn't work for me 
Can someone please shed light on this.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var ViewData_a = "<%= ViewData["a"] %>";
</script>

...

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        if(ViewData_a) {
            $('#div1').show();
        }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't access your ViewData in this manner.  You'll need to do something like putting the value into say a hidden field and then checking that.

```
if ($('.HdnFieldClassName').val() == "true")
{
  $('#div1').show();
}
```

Or something like that.

Unsure whether you can do something like

```
if ( '<%= ViewData["a"] %>' == "true"
```

I don't know about other people but I'm not a huge fan of using control names in jQuery.  I much prefer to use the class name to grab a control.

```
<input type='text' class="jQueryMyTextBox" id='MyTextBox'>

$('.jQueryMyTextBox').val()
```

It just means that if the control name changes that your code still works and you can now share the code between forms etc.

Answer (score 0):

While you're at it, consider using JSTL/EL instead of scriptlets.

So...

```
<%= ViewData["a"] %>
```

becomes...

```
<c:out value="${ViewData.a}"/>
```

JSTL/EL often gives you some things for free.  Like in this example, the value of ViewData["a"] will be entity-encoded automatically.